# Template template partial specialization only working with -std=c++1z with g++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++17, clang++

I have found that the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct X : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename> class Y, typename U>
struct X<Y<U>> : std::true_type {};

int main() {
  if (X<int>())
    std::cout << "wrong\n";

  if (X<std::vector<double>>())
    std::cout << "correct\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Only prints `correct` when compiled with `g++-7` with `-std=c++1z`. Other versions of `g++`, `clang++` or other `std` flags fail to produce correct.

Is this a bug of the current implementation, and this code should not print anything, or is something changed in C++17 which makes this code work as I expect?

Comment: Fun fact: if you make `Y` take a variadic number of arguments, it will print `correct` for clang on `-std=c++1z` and nothing for gcc on `-std=c++17` :)

Comment: Still prints `correct` with `g++-7` here..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a result of the adoption of [P0522](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) in C++17, whose motivation was, from the example:

> ```
> template <template <int> class> void FI();
> template <template <auto> class> void FA();
> template <auto> struct SA { /* ... */ };
> template <int> struct SI { /* ... */ };
> FI<SA>();  // OK; error before this paper
> FA<SI>();  // error
>
> template <template <typename> class> void FD();
> template <typename, typename = int> struct SD { /* ... */ };
> FD<SD>();  // OK; error before this paper (CWG 150)
> ```

Previously, the wording in [temp.arg.template] required template template parameters to match in kind exactly. So given:

```
template <template <class > class P> class X;

template <class T> class A;
template <class T, class U=T> class B;
template <class... > class C;
```

`X<A>` is clearly okay, but `X<B>` is ill-formed because `B` takes two template parameters (regardless if one is defaulted!) and `X<C>` is ill-formed because `P` expects one template parameter and `C` takes a pack (even if you could form a `C` with only a single parameter!)

The new wording loosens the idea of a match to one which makes more sense - if the template template-parameter is at least as specialized as the argument. That makes `X<B>` and `X<C>` both work.

Hence, in C++17, `X<std::vector<double>>` should pick the specialization. But before C++17, it should pick the primary. gcc is doing the right thing.

Comment: a quick glance at that paper makes it seem like it's about non-type template parameters, which isn't the case here.  Can you be more specific/dumbed-down about how this is relevant in this case?

Comment: @xaxxon Glance longer? It's not about non-type template parameters at all - it's about template templates. The `FD<SD>()` example is precisely what OP is doing.