# Compound template

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I'm trying to make "compound" template type. Something like this

```
template <typename A, typename T>
class configurator
{
public:
    configurator(const A<T> & adapter) : m_adapter(adapter) {}
private:
    A<T> m_adapter;
};
```

Compiler complains with

```
error: expected ')'
    configurator(const A<T> & adapter
                        ^
```

Why this is not working? Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

`A` is declared as [type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Type_template_parameter); you can't use it as template-name and specify template argument for it.

You want [template template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). e.g.

```
template <template <typename> typename A, typename T>
class configurator
```

BTW if `A` is supposed to work with multiple template arguments you could specify `A` with [template parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```
template <template <typename...> typename A, typename T>
class configurator
```

Comment: The OP should beware that this will only work if `A` has *exactly* one typename argument.  It won't work for (eg) `std::vector`, because although that is usually used with one template argument, it actually has an allocator, and may have additional, implementation specific, parameters.

Comment: @MartinBonner [It works since C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c458b4fd6cea62d1).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you have more links about it? It seems [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0fuyRoXsb1IuK7vT) doesn't support that..

Comment: @songyuanyao I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645226/template-template-parameter-and-default-values), so maybe clang just doesn't support it yet?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oooh!  That's shiny.  Excellent.