# Why is the partial specialisation of a template template argument not working?

Tags: templates, c++14, partial-specialization

I am considering `Class1, Class2, Class3`.

`Class2` and `Class3` have a partial specialisation with `int`, so they are identical in their definition.

On the other hand, `Class1` has a specialisation for `Class3<T>` and for a general template template with only one argument, i.e. `Unary<T>`. So `Class1` has no specialisation for `Class2<T>`.

It happens that `Class1 <Class3<T>>::type` is actually `Class3<T>`. Indeed I explicitly wrote the specialisation. However, the compiler says `Class1 <Class2<T>>::type` it is not defined. But I defined the specialisation for a the template template case, `Class1<Unary<T>>`. Why is the compiler not recognising it? How can I make the compiler choose the most specialised case (`Class1 <Class3<T>>::type`), if it exists, and, if does not, the template template case (`Class1<Unary<T>>`)? Thank you

```
template<typename...T>
class Class1;

template<typename...T>
class Class2;

template<typename...T>
class Class3;

template<>
class Class2<int>
{};

template<>
class Class3<int>
{};

template<typename T>
class Class1<Class3<T>>
{
 public:
  using type=Class3<T>;
};

template<template<class> class Unary, typename T>
class Class1<Unary<T>>
{
 public:
  using type=Unary<T>;
};
```

Comment: Interesting: Compare gcc and clang in the case of [matching an actual unary template](https://godbolt.org/z/13dooB), vs [matching a variadic template](https://godbolt.org/z/68kIWV) against the unary template template argument. Both compilers do the former, but clang rejects the latter (while gcc accepts it). I assume you are using clang? (Both are also happy given a variadic template for deducing a variadic template template argument: https://godbolt.org/z/Fhrb4B)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You know that "Class1 has no specialisation for Class2<T>" because the unary specialization is related to a "template template with only one argument" but you're surprised that "However, the compiler says Class1 <Class2<T>>::type it is not defined. But I defined the specialisation for a the template template case, Class1<Unary<T>>".

Comment: @MaxLanghof - observe that both compilers fail with the later (also gcc) compiling with C++14 instead of C++17. The language is changed in C++17 so I suspect that g++ is conformant and clang++ isn't.

Comment: @max66 It boils down to "can you pass a variadic template as an unary template template argument?". Based on the 3 main compiler votes, it seems that the answer is "in C++14 you can't, in C++17 you can". But that's the question.

Comment: @MaxLanghof yup, C++17 reduced the constraints on matching variadic template template arguments and template template arguments with defaulted values

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645226/template-template-parameter-and-default-values

Answer (score 1):

Before C++17 such template:

```
template<template<class> class Unary, typename T>
class Class1<Unary<T>>
```

should not mach with variadic templates. Same for templates with defaulted arguments (check this with `std::vector` for example) - [Template template parameter and default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645226/template-template-parameter-and-default-values). It was a defect in standard and fix came in C++17