# How to static assert whether all types of a tuple fulfill some condition?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, type-traits

I have some type traits `SomeTraits` from which I can extract whether a type `T` fulfills some condition, through `SomeTraits<T>::value`.
How would one go over all the types of a given `std::tuple<>` and check (through say a static assert) whether they all fulfill the above condition? e.g.

```
using MyTypes = std::tuple<T1, T2, T3>;
// Need some way to do something like
static_assert(SomeTupleTraits<MyTypes>::value, "MyTypes must be a tuple that blabla...");
```

where `SomeTupleTraits` would check whether `SomeTraits<T>::value == true` for each type inside `MyTypes`?

I am restricted to C++14.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a one liner (newlines optional), you can do something like:

```cpp
// (c++20)
static_assert([]<typename... T>(std::type_identity<std::tuple<T...>>) {
    return (SomeTrait<T>::value && ...);
}(std::type_identity<MyTypes>{}));
```

Or you can create a helper trait to do it:

```cpp
// (c++17)
template<template<typename, typename...> class Trait, typename Tuple>
struct all_of;

template<template<typename, typename...> class Trait, typename... Types>
struct all_of<Trait, std::tuple<Types...>> : std::conjunction<Trait<Types>...> {};

static_assert(all_of<SomeTrait, MyTypes>::value);
```

---

Or in C++11, you can reimplement [`std::conjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) inside the helper trait:

```cpp
template<template<typename, typename...> class Trait, typename Tuple>
struct all_of;

template<template<typename, typename...> class Trait>
struct all_of<Trait, std::tuple<>> : std::true_type {};

template<template<typename, typename...> class Trait, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct all_of<Trait, std::tuple<First, Rest...>> :
    std::conditional<bool(Trait<First>::value),
                     all_of<Trait, std::tuple<Rest...>>,
                     std::false_type>::type::type {};

static_assert(all_of<SomeTrait, MyTypes>::value, "");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems `std::conjunction` is a C++17 feature (and `std::type_identity` C++20). I am restricted to C++14. Is there another C++14 compatible method that could work with a helper trait? Or is the most straightforward method simply to reimplement `std::conjunction`?

Comment: @zhanginou Reimplementing `std::conjunction` is pretty easy to do in C++14, but you can do it directly as I've edited my answer to do so

Comment: Thanks! And how would one modify the above if the Trait uses SFINAE as the second template argument, e.g. `template <typename T, typename = void> struct SomeTrait : std::false_type { }; template <typename T> struct SomeTrait<T, std::enable_if_t<SomeCondition<T>::value> : std::true_type { }`? With the above method, the compiler complains that `type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class Trait, class Tuple> struct all_of'`

Comment: This is [CWG150](https://wg21.link/CWG150) (See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48645226). I've added an extra `typename...` parameter pack to the template template argument so it should work even in C++11